# How does one go about deleting records from an array with Joins

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join

I have a query with multiple joins in it. After I take the results and run it through a Id-checker I want to be able to delete records from that array where the IDDestination equals $ID.

Since this query has joins on it and I am filtering them based on one of the joined tables, How do I go about deleting those records from the array based off that joined table?

And I only wanted this to happen after the user confirms.

```
$query = "
select d.IDCourse,
 d.name as course_name,
 d.slug,
 d.short_description,
d.address,
e.city_name,
e.state_code,
d.zip,
e.city_slug,
e.state_slug,
h.IDDestination,
LOWER(e.iso_code) as country_slug, a.*,
b.IDTeetimeType,
c.name as teetime_type,
b.start_time,b.end_time,

(case dayofweek(a.teetime_dt)
        when 1 then `b`.`sun`
        when 2 then `b`.`mon`
        when 3 then `b`.`tue`
        when 4 then `b`.`wed`
        when 5 then `b`.`thu`
        when 6 then `b`.`fri`
        when 7 then `b`.`sat`
    end) AS `price`, g.tax_rate, f.alias
from cart_course_teetimes a
join course_priceplan b
on a.IDCoursePricePlan = b.IDCoursePricePlan
join course_teetime_type c
on b.IDTeetimeType = c.IDTeetimeType
join course d
on b.IDCourse = d.IDCourse
join vw_cities e
on d.IDCity = e.IDCity
join destinations_cities h
on h.IDCity= d.IDCity

LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM media_mapping WHERE is_main_item=1 AND IDGalleryType=3) f
    ON d.IDGallery = f.IDGallery
left join course_tax
g on a.IDCourseTax = g.IDCourseTax


where a.IDCart = :cart_id
order by d.name, a.teetime_dt, b.start_time;";
    $prepared = array(
        "cart_id"   => $idCart,
    );
    $conn     = new DBConnection();
    $results  = $conn->fetch($query, $prepared);
    $conn     = null;

    $results = !empty($results) ? $results : array();


    $id = null;

    foreach($results as $row) {
        // Set ID for the first record.
        if($id === null)
            $id = $row['IDDestination'];



        // will stay true, otherwise it's false and we should kill the loop.
        if($id != $row['IDDestination']) {
            $newid=$row['IDDestination'];

           echo "<script type='text/javascript'> emptycart();</script>";
        $query = "DELETE FROM cart_course_teetimes a WHERE  h.IDDestination='.$id.'";
            $res =mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect PHP:

```
   $query = "DELETE FROM cart_course_teetimes a WHERE  h.IDDestination='.$id.'"
```

You're already inside a `"`-quoted string, so `.` PHP concatenation operators aren't operators, they're just a period.

You want either of these instead:

```
   $query = "DELETE FROM cart_course_teetimes a WHERE  h.IDDestination='" . $id . "'";
   $query = "DELETE FROM cart_course_teetimes a WHERE  h.IDDestination='$id'"
```

Right now you're producing

```
 ... WHERE h.IDDestination = .42.
```

which is not valid SQL.

Plus it appears you're mixing database libraries. You've got `$conn->fetch()` which implies you're using one of the OO db libraries (mysqli? pdo? custom wrapper?). But you then call `mysql_query()`. Unless you've EXPLICITLY called `mysql_connect()`, that delete query will never execute. Database connections made in one of the libraries are utterly useless in any of the other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still getting a FATAL error coming up saying Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a WHERE h.IDDestination='7'' at line 1.... This must has something to do with the a for the cart_course_teetimes

Comment: might try `cart_course_teetimes AS a`. I don't see anything in mysql's docs that explicitly says `as` is optional in a delete query. it is optional in selects, but nothing in the delete docs says so.